# Laravel how to choose between multiple images as og:image

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-opengraph

I'm building a `laravel`-application and I want to add some `facebook-opengraph`-meta stuff. For example in `wordpress` you can use the `yoast`-plugin so when you share a page or an article you can choose which image you want to set as the `og:image`. How is this possible in `laravel`?

Right now, I just have the plain

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ path/to/some/image/ }} ">
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: That html looks fine, I don't really get the problem.

Comment: Now, you are just setting the image url "statically" in your blade view. It looks like you will need to include some logic in your template or even in your controller (if complex decision tree) to decide which image is displayed in every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have an array of images , $images[$data->iamge_position] .. store the image position while storing image in database.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@if(Storage::exists('pathimg')) 
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ Storage::url('pathimg') }} ">
@endif
```

to check if file exists and get real path